# Magnetic Dipole moment and angular momentum

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum

I came across various charge systems in books and noticed that for every system the ratio of magnetic dipole moment to the angular momentum came out to be $\frac{Q}{2M} $ where Q is the total charge on the system and M is the mass of the system if the system of charge is moving with a constant angular velocity about an axis.
Examples - A uniform ring rotating with constant angular velocity, a uniform disc, a hollow sphere, a solid sphere.

So is it true that for any such arbitrary rotating charged system this ratio is always $\frac{Q}{2M} $??
Also if it is then is there any proof for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio